# Crazy barn find generator

Tags: circuit-design

I found a scruffy old generator on an auction site.

As it's 'we're all home' I bought it for a very good price, stripped it and cleaned everything, then mounted it on a board with screw terminals for ease of use. (See picture below.)

It's had very little use - the brushes are very long, not worn down.

That's the background of this little monster and now the 'can I do that' bit.

It has two outlets, (calling left and right) the motor draws 3amperes at 12V according to my clamp meter, the left output is showing 1888 volts on my multimeter set at 600V DC and is stable.

The righthand outlet is showing 1475V (can't see a decimal point on either display) and that is a rough average because it's flicking up and down by twenty or so.

Now, this is the question:

Can I have it self powering and charging a 24V battery bank?

I'd love a list of bits and a diagram.

[image: the generator]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: An electrical machine of this type cannot "power itself".  You can put mechanical energy into a generator by spinning it and get electrical energy out, or you can put electrical energy in and get rotary motion out.  There is some chance that what you have is a rotary converter, which would be a motor spinning two generators.  If you're reading >600V on a 600V rated volt meter, you should immediately disconnect and find another way to measure.

Comment: Note that while it steps up voltage there's no magic involved; it'll turn 12V 3A into 540V at mere mA. Nice interesting find though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is a [dynamotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor%E2%80%93generator) to provide high voltages for a mobile, vacuum tube-based radio station of one or another kind, from just a car battery voltage. It is similar by appearance to the dynamotor seen in that Wikipedia article. It probably has military origins and powered up something serious and with transmitter. Just for a car radio, seems overkill. This also would explain why it is little used.

It is an interesting piece of technology but I really cannot think anything useful  you could do in these days with such a converter. If to power a nostalgic tube amp, it is probably for that too noisy and the amp should come with its own transformer. Careful with high voltages it produces.

Comment: I don't know why it's going so nuts. there are original stickers on it that I found under the original paint. on the left it says 540v and on the right it says 265v. the sticker on the top says,240 volts power unit generator, input 12volts output 240volts.

Comment: @Derek Bull those are the voltage ratings at some specific rated load.  If you attach a load the output voltage will drop with any increase of output current.  Any energy conversion has losses and an older motor/generator might be only 80 or 90% efficient, and you're converting energy twice, so the overall efficiency is the product of the efficiency of each stage.  If you have two 80% efficient stages, your total efficiency is 64%.  Usually devices are designed to be most efficient close to rated current.